# How can I stop opening video in full screen in Safari?

Tags: html, video, safari, frontend

How can I stop opening video in full screen in Safari? The video starts playing on click on the button, which shows only in browsers where autoplay video is forbidden.

[Demo](http://silencer.website/tomatdesign/one-project_video.html)

Answer (score 5):

add the `playsinline` property to your view, as described in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_0.html

eg

```
<video autoplay preload="auto" playsinline controls>
    <source src="....">
</video>
```

Comment: Erm, it is the old version of Safari, it doesn't work anymore

Comment: why are you still using an old version of Safari? Apple don't support it on Windows, or more than a couple of versions back

Comment: what? I have Safari 11.0.1. I was talking about an example of code which is for Safari 10

Comment: It's a old question and anwser, but this worked on Safari iOS 12.1.3...

Comment: Still working for me on iOS 14 Safari